# How to pass @ref to elements into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I'm using Blazor WASM and I try to pass @bind from razor to elements in JavaScript. The elements need to hold `input value`. I have tried with `autofocus` and try to pass @bind into `db.collection('calculate').add({` but didn't work.

**Javascript**

```
export function localbase(InNumberPatient, InInterval, InMHCProduct, InComProduct) {

  db.collection('calculate').add({
        InNumberPatient: + InNumberPatient,
        InInterval:  + InInterval,
        InMHCProduct: + InMHCProduct,
        InComProduct: + InComProduct,
      })
    db.collection('calculate').get().then(calculate => {
    console.log(calculate)
    })
  }
```

**Razor page**

```
 @code{
    private int InNumberPatient;
private string InInterval;
private string InMHCProduct;
private string InComProduct;
  string name = string.Empty;
  IJSObjectReference module;

 private async Task AddDB()
    {
     module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./scripts/Localbase.js");
    await module.InvokeVoidAsync("localbase", InNumberPatient, InInterval, InMHCProduct, InComProduct);
     Console.WriteLine("Berjaya");

 } 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to pass input value to js,you only need to bind input value.Here is a demo:

razor:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
<h3>Test</h3>
InNumberPatient
<input @bind="InNumberPatient" />
InInterval
<input @bind="InInterval" />
InMHCProduct
<input @bind="InMHCProduct" />
InComProduct
<input @bind="InComProduct" />
<button @onclick="@(()=>AddDB())">submit</button>
@code {
    private int InNumberPatient;
    private string InInterval;
    private string InMHCProduct;
    private string InComProduct;
    string name = string.Empty;
    IJSObjectReference module;
    private async Task AddDB()
    {
        module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./scripts/Localbase.js");
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("localbase", InNumberPatient, InInterval, InMHCProduct, InComProduct);
        Console.WriteLine("Berjaya");

    }
}
```

localbase.js:

```
export function localbase(InNumberPatient, InInterval, InMHCProduct, InComProduct) {
    console.log("InNumberPatient:" + InNumberPatient + ";InInterval:" + InInterval + ";InMHCProduct:" + InMHCProduct + ";InComProduct:" + InComProduct + ";");
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I have change to bind but for javascript I have problem, I still need to use ` db.collection('calculate') add({ ` and `db.collection('calculate').get().then(calculate => {
    console.log(calculate)
    })` .